# iOS SplitView Controller, Programatically Change View With Multiple Storyboards

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

Hopefully someone can help.

I've got an app that uses the `UISplitViewController` however I've now had to start using multiple `storyboards` because i've got a large amount of `views` and Xcode was starting to run really slow. I've moved moved the `UIViewControllers` to multiple `storyboards`.

The `Master View` is built from static cells, so when the user selects the cell I normally change the `view` by pushing a `segue`.

I'm now wondering how to programmatically change the detail view of a `UISplitViewController`?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subclass UISplitViewController and set your root splitViewController to that class. Then add this method to your UISplitViewController subclass:

```
-(void)setDetailControllerTo:(UIViewController *)detailController withNavControllerTitle:(NSString *)title {
    [detailController view]; // this line forces the viewDidLoad method to be called

    if (title) {
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        [navController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
        detailController.title = title;

        NSArray *viewControllers=@[self.mainController.viewControllers[0],navController];
        self.mainController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    } else {
        NSArray *viewControllers=@[self.mainController.viewControllers[0],detailController];
        self.mainController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    }
}
```

To call this method do something like this from the master view controller:

```
FixedSplitViewController *splitController = (FixedSplitViewController*) self.splitViewController;

CurrentEventViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CurrentEventViewController"];
// add any setup code here
[splitController setDetailControllerTo:controller withNavControllerTitle:@"Current Event"];
```

A lot of my projects require the splitviewcontroller to always show the master view so I use this subclass to keep the master view from hiding on portrait rotation.